# Sumproduct not working

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I need to execute my excel formula on vba. Here's the formula:

```
=((SUMPRODUCT(-(Details!$C$7:$C$1182=A3),-(Details!$E$7:$E$1182=B3), -(Details!$S$7:$S$1182="Delivered"), -(Details!$G$7:$G$1182=C3), Details!$N$7:$N$1182)))
```

And my code is:

```
ws1.Range("I2:I" & last) = Evaluate("SumProduct(-(Details!C = A3), -(Details!E = B3), -(Details!S = 'Delivered'), -(Details!G = C3), Details!N)")
```

My sumproduct takes values from other sheets, but it is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write -- instead of  - for your logical tests

Evaluate("SumProduct(--(Details!C = A3), --(Details!E = B3), --(Details!S = 'Delivered'), --(Details!G = C3), Details!N)")

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it gives an error (#value)